# How to Access the celery result?

Tags: django, celery

I want a message to be displayed  in my `web-application` (which is using `django framework` ) for a particular changes in some tasks .I have implemented `celery` but cant make it run as a daemon process and I want to access those changes in UI. Can anyone suggest me ways to do so?

I have been able to configure the celery but not make it work continuously in background.My actual requirement is if there is any changes in the celery I want it to invoke a message in my UI.is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Celery is an asynchronous task queue, and Django is built on the request-response HTTP loop.  In order to access the results of a celery task, you have to store it somewhere.  Redis is typically the default for a backend result store.

In order to access it in a web UI, you have to either access the redis db directly from the client via interval polling, or expose an API endpoint to do that for you.  The latter would be more preferable.

Comment: Can we have something like store the result in redis backend only when the condition is satisfied and as soon as it gets saved we send a notification message to our UI. @jason

Comment: yes.  http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_ignore_result

Comment: The issue is I am not able to access the redis-database

Comment: Then that's a configuration or access issue, and doesn't have anything to do with celery itself